Usage or alternative for oro/doctrine-extensions in Symfony7
my Symfony7 project need some SQL Functions especially dayofyear.
I added oro/doctrine-extensions to my composer.json file and added the doctrine:orm:dql: functions accordingly.
However I receive several errors by using the function im my repository class:
Compile Error: Declaration of Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\AbstractPlatformAwareFunctionNode::getSql(Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker) must be compatible with Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode::getSql(Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker): string

The version of oro/doctrine-extensions I use is 2.0.2. Composer outdated gives my 2.0.4 but there seems to be some restriction in using it. I also don't know if this solves the issue.
Does someone has a solution using oro/doctrine-extensions together with symfony7 or are there alternatives for using something like
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cm');
$qb->select('cm')->where('dayofyear(cm.birthDate) >= dayofyear(:curdate)');
$qb->andWhere('dayofyear(cm.birthDate) <= dayofyear(:curdate) + 7');

